# How to make use of 2 versions of a Jar file in a single Java class Java 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have 2 Jar files,

Jar1 is located in my `src/main/resources` called engine.jar

Jar2 is located in my Maven Dependencies library, also called engine.jar

How can I directly make use of the classes and methods inside Jar1 and then later make use of the classes and methods inside Jar2.

I'm writing a simple commandline app, which will effectively regressively test my new code versus the old.

**Edit:**

I tried doing this:

```
public void setup() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    CalculationService.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com/company/aero/fs/sys/api/CalculationService");
}
```

What I tried to do here is to use class loader to get a class within Jar1 to load. It's location is in the main resources folder.

This ofcourse didn't work.

**Edit:**

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to test regressively my new engine.

Calling the classes and methods of Engine1 produces some output files (checksums). And I want to do the same thing with Engine2 which will also produce output checksum files. Then finally I want to compare the output files of Engine1 (jar1) and Engine2 (jar2). If they are the same, then engines are working correctly and I haven;t broken anything in Engine2 (new engine).

Any alternative suggestions as how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Do the two jar files contain the same classes (same fully qualified class names) or different sets of classes? Is there any overlap?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, both Jars contain the almost the same classes in the same packages. Jar2 just has additional classes and some refactored logic but the class names and packages are the same.

Comment: You might be able to accomplish this with a custom classloader, but that can be a real pain to get right and to debug.  You should probably ask yourself if this isn't an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Do you _really_ need to do this? If so, a custom classloader is probably the only solution.  You would need to load `jar1` classes in one classloader and `jar2` classes in a different one. How to write one is way beyond the scope of StackOverflow, and there are good tutorials available on the web.

Comment: Nice article on the XY problem. I'm starting to think whether you are right about me really needing to do something like this. I'll add another edit to my post about what I'm really trying to accomplish here. Perhaps someone can suggest me a more viable approach